# Date picker is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to add a calender in my application. The following code that I have is not working in codeigntier but it works fine if I put it into another folder outside codeigniter. Would you please kindly help me find out what the problem is? 
Thanks in Advance

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
//get class into the page


require_once('tc_calendar.php');



  $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
  $myCalendar->setIcon ("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
  $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
  $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
  $myCalendar->setYearInterval(1971, 2035);
  $myCalendar->dateAllow('1971-01-01', '2035-01-01');
  $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
  //$myCalendar->setHeight(350);      
  //$myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");
  $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');
  $myCalendar->writeScript();
  ?>

     </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: How did you load this in codeigniter? Is this a view or a plain html file?

Comment: If I load the above code in a plain html file, it works fine but when I load it on a view file in codeigniter it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Ah, where did you place your plain html file if it's located outside codeigniter? I think it may be related to codeigniter not finding `calendar/calendar.js` and `calendar/calendar.css` once it's loaded as a view.

Comment: Normally, you should place your `calendar/calendar.js` and `calendar/calendar.js` in your codeigniter app`s `public` folder. Also, `require_once('tc_calendar.php');` this line causes a fatal error when `tc_calendar.php` is not found, so this could be one of the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the paths to your assets are off. Try using `base_url()` in the calls to your assets and see if that helps. Your JS and CSS files would be loaded like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>calendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

`base_url()` will get you to the root of the application, so if the *calendar* directory is not at the root then update that path accordingly. Inspect the HTML that is produced and see if it is actually loading the assets.